# How to change / replace a failed "system" disk on EMC Clariion CX500?

Tags: diskmanagement, emc, drive-failure, replace, clariion

On the first DAE, the first 5 disks are considered "special" because they host the OS of the storage array.

**One of those 5 disks is faulty : what is the procedure to change it?**

By the way, what kind of RAID configuration is set up on those?

Comment: RAID 5, by default.  You should probably hit up EMC Powerlink to get the documentation... assuming you have a support agreement (they "paywall" their tech documentation, so you need a legit warranty or support agreement to access it).

Comment: @HopelessN00b Thanks. Also, if I still had support, I would not ask the question here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are only 4 OS drives. Slots 0, 1, 2, & 3. The OS drives are mirrored. The procedure to replace one is to simply pull the faulted drive and put the new one in. It will automatically start rebuilding and mirror back to that drive. If I remember correctly, drive 0 is mirrored to 2 and 1 is mirrored to 3.